# Install Ubuntu 16.04 No Audio

Tags: 16.04, sound, speakers

I have dell laptop inspirion 15 3000 series i386 Model.
I recently installed Ubuntu 16.04 but audio is not coming.
I check the all the sound setting
Speaker,Headphone is not muted .
Anyone Know the solution let me know 
Thank You.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/16.04/ubuntu-help/sound-nosound.html you might get something from here!

Comment: Alternatively `aplay -l` paste this in terminal and update your question with output.